# Laravel JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES doesn't work

Tags: json, laravel

For some reason this does not escape my slashes.

Whenever I manually do `echo json_encode($relation, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)` for example then it does work but it doesn't work with Laravel responses like below. Any fix or workaround?

```
        return response()->json([
            'card' => $card[0],
            'company' => $company[0],
            'identity' => $identity[0],
            'haulier_declarations' => $relation,
        ], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$options = app('request')->header('accept-charset') == 'utf-8' ? JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE : null;
return response()->json([
            'card' => $card[0],
            'company' => $company[0],
            'identity' => $identity[0],
            'haulier_declarations' => $relation,
        ], 200, [], $options);
```

Comment: Same result :-( For now I have fixed it by json_encoding manually and feeding that output to response().

Comment: try this may be this will help.

`$response = json_encode([
            'card' => $card[0],
            'company' => $company[0],
            'identity' => $identity[0],
            'haulier_declarations' => $relation,
        ],
         JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
);

return response($response)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');`